# Eloquent `with()` with filtering based on relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have this tables.

[image]

And this model relations, this relations works fine.

```
class Item extends Model
{

    public function translations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ItemTranslations::class);
    }
}
```

```
class ItemTranslation extends Model
{

    public function language()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Language::class);
    }
}
```

I need to return a list of items with the translations, but only the translations related to a specific language.

I can't have this query working, im getting all translations of each item, not only the one filtered with this query. The language related to the translation is not needed on the result.

```
$query = Item::query();

$query->with('translations')->when('language',function($query) use ($ISOlanguage) {
    return $query->where('languages.ISO_code', '=', $ISOlanguage);
});

return $query->paginate();
```

Any idea who i can have this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

So what you want to do is constraining eager loading

```php
Item::with(["translations" => function ($query) use ($ISOlanguage) {
    $query->where('language.ISO_code', $ISOlanguage);
}])->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: When listing all (or some) items, want to have also the translations loaded, but only the translations related to a specific language

Comment: With my example you load all `translations` where the `languages` `ISO_code` equals your `$ISOlanguage`: Or what did you mean?

Comment: Thanks for your response, for some reason that is not working, i update my question with the whole query. Im getting this error:
```
Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "language"
LINE 1: ...item_translations"."language_id" in (1, 2) and "language...
                                                                                         ^ (SQL: select * from "item_translations" where "item_translations"."language_id" in (1, 2) and "language"."ISO_code" = EN)
```

Comment: Even if i use `languages` which is the real table name, i get the same issue

Comment: Does it work with my example in the question without your `query` and `paginate`? If so you can use my example and replace `get()` with `paginate()`

Comment: Is not working even if i directly copy your code, i get the same error i post above.

Comment: I tried id myself with an example project and it worked. Any errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215663/discussion-between-julian-s-and-ricardo-albear).

Answer (score 2):

I finally have it working

```
Item::with(['translations' => function($query) use ($ISOlanguage) {
   $query->whereHas('language', function($query) use ($ISOlanguage) {
       $query->where('ISO_code', '=', $ISOlanguage);
   });
}])->get();
```

Thanks @julian-s for your help!